# How to make query of each parent only three 0r four child objects get in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a list of videos which are belong from some of channels. I want to get only three videos per channel and pass as return value. My code is slice the list of videos not for all channel it's get only three objects. But i want to get each channel of three videos.

I don't understand how can i do that...

models.py

```py
class Channels(UserTrackTimeStampMixin):
    channel_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(YTCategory, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)


class YTVideo(TimestampMixin):
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channels, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

```py
def each_channel_three_videos(request):

    videos = video.YTVideo.objects.select_related('channel')\
        .filter(channel__category__slug='vlogs')\
        .order_by('-per_sec_views')[:3]

    context = {
        'videos': videos,
    }
    return render(request, 'videos.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you post your Models as well?- just so we can see how Channels+Videos connect. You want to get 3 videos from each channel; 5 total channels = show 15 videos (3 from each) - This is a good one! idk if you can do it through Django functions, but I'd love for someone to prove me wrong

Comment: Yes i want to do this `you want to get 3 videos from each channel; 5 total channels = show 15 videos (3 from each)`. Please take a look my question is updated with models.